# strcmp does not compare 2 adjacent strings in array of pointer to characters properly

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I make a c program to alphabetize a 10 string array and I am struggling at the point of using strcmp(). This line consists of the string-handling comparison function doesn't compare strings on the right side. This is my code so far. Appreciate for your helps!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void bubbleSort(char * const townAry[SIZE], size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    char * const townPtr[SIZE] = {"Alviso","Milpitas","Berryessa","Alum Rock","Los Gatos",
                                "Campbell","Cupertino","Sagatora","Sunnyvale","Mountain View"};

    bubbleSort(townPtr,SIZE);

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n",townPtr[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    // expected output:
    // Alum Rock
    // Alviso
    // Berryessa
    // Campbell
    // Cupertino
    // Los Gatos
    // Milpitas
    // Mountain View
    // Sagatora
    // Sunnyvale
    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(char * const townAry[SIZE], size_t size)
{
    void swap(char *town1Ptr, char *town2Ptr);
    unsigned int pass;
    size_t j;

    for (pass = 0; pass < size - 1; ++pass)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j)
        {
            if(strcmp(townAry[j], townAry[j + 1]) > 0) // problem: this line doesn't compare 2 adjacent strings
            {
                swap(townAry[j], townAry[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void swap(char *town1Ptr, char *town2Ptr)
{
    char * hold = town1Ptr; 
    *town1Ptr = *town2Ptr;
    *town2Ptr = *hold;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are swapping your pointer to string literals incorrectly the swap function should be:

```
void swap(char **town1Ptr, char **town2Ptr)
{
    char* hold = *town1Ptr; 
    *town1Ptr = *town2Ptr;
    *town2Ptr = hold;
}
```

Make sure you pass your variables correctly to the swap function

```
swap(&townAry[j], &townAry[j + 1]);
```

And remove all const keywords from `char * const townPtr` and `void bubbleSort(char * const...`

Comment: @self I need to fix the line if(strcmp(townAry[j], townAry[j + 1]) > 0) since it doesn't work. The swap function is another problem and it may appear later.

Comment: Also, the `SIZE` in the parameter declaration `char * const townAry[SIZE]` is useless. The declaration is equivalent to `char *const townAry[]` which is equivalent to `char ** const townAry`. It really is just a pointer, not an array. Arrays cannot actually passed into functions in C; the declarations are adjusted to pointer type.The array form of the declaration, with a size, can serve as documentation when fixed size data is being passed around, but that is moot if you're also passing a `size` parameter.

Comment: @user3077220  That line appears not to work because you're scrambling the data. Your swap routine is trying to exchange the first character of the two strings, rather than the strings themselves. (Since the strings are string literals, this is actually undefined behavior: string literals are not modifiable.) If your compiler and run-time actually allow the modification of literals then your `swap("abc", "def")` mutates these inputs into `"dbc", "aef"`.   In many modern environments, attempting to modify a string literal will crash the program, though.

Comment: I understand my problem, do you have any other solution to make this kind of program? Is my solution good?

Comment: @Kaz After fixing, I got the result:
Alum Rock
Alum Rock
Alum Rock
Alum Rock
Campbell
Campbell
Cupertino
Mountain View
Mountain View
Mountain View

Why is so?

Comment: @user3077220 Sorry there was a mistake in my swap(), now fixed. :-/

Comment: @self it's so hard to debug inside the function strcmp(). When I debug this line the address and the value of the first string "Alviso" always shows up.

Comment: @user3077220 Should work now, just make sure bubblesort is correct.

Comment: it works, but i feel less comfortable because I have no idea why it works

Comment: @self I know this kind of program needs strcmp() and bubblesort, but the code makes me very confused.

Comment: @user3077220 Keep coding/learning until you get it. There is no easy path.

Comment: @self my problem is pointer technique. I need to practice more in this area.